# Can't run heroku rake db:migrate even with 'pg' gem installed

Tags: postgresql, heroku, rake

I'm trying to run `heroku rake db:migrate`, and I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is   not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've followed the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296683/rails-3-1-pushing-to-heroku-errors-installing-postgres-adapter), namely to:

1. add 'pg' to Gemfile, under :production
2. run bundle install --without production

But I still get the error.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

  gem "rails", "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.0.0.pre2'
  gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.2'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
end

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.4'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'growl_notify'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Someone on #RubyOnRails suggested it was an incorrectly configured database.yml for production, but to quote the Heroku site itself, "To ease deployment of typical Rails applications, Heroku automatically generates a new database.yml file on deployment."

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: few questions. After bundling `without --production` did you commit and push both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to Heroku? Also, what OS are you running on locally?

Comment: Thanks, John. I'm a bit red-faced to admit that the answer was simply to commit and push to heroku again. Oy.

Comment: easily done. We've all done it :) Given it as an answer so you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Double check you've commit and pushed both the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to Heroku.