# Redmine on heroku rake error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, redmine, rails-postgresql

I am trying to deploy redmine on heroku. While trying to rake db:migrate I get following error:

```
[desktop:~/redmine-2.3]$heroku run rake db:migrate                   
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2102
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Plugins in vendor/plugins (/app/vendor/plugins) are no longer allowed. Please, put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your Redmine directory (/app/plugins)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (cannot load such file -- java)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.9/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/java.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.9/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.9/lib/arjdbc/jdbc.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.9/lib/arjdbc/postgresql.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-1.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
/app/lib/plugins/acts_as_activity_provider/init.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
/app/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
/app/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It says to install postgresql adapter though I've already installed it. Could you please advise what is the problem

```
> [desktop:~/redmine-2.3]$git push heroku master Counting objects: 7,
> done. Delta compression using up to 8 threads. Compressing objects:
> 100% (4/4), done. Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 397 bytes, done. Total
> 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
> 
> -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
> -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
> -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
>        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
>        Using rake (10.0.4)
>        Using i18n (0.6.1)
>        Using multi_json (1.7.6)
>        Using activesupport (3.2.13)
>        Using builder (3.0.0)
>        Using activemodel (3.2.13)
>        Using erubis (2.7.0)
>        Using journey (1.0.4)
>        Using rack (1.4.5)
>        Using rack-cache (1.2)
>        Using rack-test (0.6.2)
>        Using hike (1.2.2)
>        Using tilt (1.4.1)
>        Using sprockets (2.2.2)
>        Using actionpack (3.2.13)
>        Using mime-types (1.23)
>        Using polyglot (0.3.3)
>        Using treetop (1.4.14)
>        Using mail (2.5.4)
>        Using actionmailer (3.2.13)
>        Using arel (3.0.2)
>        Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
>        Using activerecord (3.2.13)
>        Using activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.9)
>        Using jdbc-postgres (9.2.1002.1)
>        Using activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter (1.2.9)
>        Using pg (0.15.1)
>        Using activerecord-postgresql-adapter (0.0.1)
>        Using activeresource (3.2.13)
>        Using coderay (1.0.9)
>        Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
>        Using json (1.8.0)
>        Using rdoc (3.12.2)
>        Using thor (0.18.1)
>        Using railties (3.2.13)
>        Using jquery-rails (2.0.3)
>        Using net-ldap (0.3.1)
>        Using ruby-openid (2.1.8)
>        Using rack-openid (1.3.1)
>        Using bundler (1.3.2)
>        Using rails (3.2.13)
>        Using rest-client (1.6.7)
>        Using rmagick (2.13.2)
>        Using sequel (3.20.0)
>        Using sinatra (1.0)
>        Using taps (0.3.24)
>        Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
>        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
> -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
> -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
>        Running: rake assets:precompile
>        Asset precompilation completed (1.79s)
> -----> WARNINGS:
>        you have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
>        To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:"
>        ruby '2.0.0'"
>        # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information."
> -----> Rails plugin injection
>        Injecting rails_log_stdout
>        Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
> -----> Discovering process types
>        Procfile declares types      -> (none)
>        Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
> 
> -----> Compiled slug size: 38.9MB
> -----> Launching... done, v14
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296683/rails-3-1-pushing-to-heroku-errors-installing-postgres-adapter